# add variable to url file get php

Tags: php

I have a variable define

```
$commsIP = ['192.168.1.1'];
```

I am trying to add it to a url

```
$commsDisplay = file_get_contents("http://www.dangergaming.com/comms/$commsIP");
```

but I get the following error

> Notice: Array to string conversion

but if I put the link like so

```
$commsDisplay = file_get_contents("http://www.dangergaming.com/comms/192.168.1.1");
```

It displays fine.

Comment: If it is a single value, then why do you make an array out of it in the first place? Remove those square brackets!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$commsDisplay = file_get_contents("http://www.dangergaming.com/comms/".$commsIP[0]);
```

or you could not declare it as array

```
$commsIP ='192.168.1.1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You defined the variable as an Array, which is why it's saying it can't convert from an Array to a string. Placing []'s around the variable signifies that it's an array.

Just remove the []'s and it will work fine.

```
$comssIP = '192.168.1.1';
```

Answer (score 0):

You put brackets around the IP address, when you do this it has the same functionality as an array.

If you change this:

```
$commsIP = ['192.168.1.1'];
```

To this:

```
$commsIP = '192.168.1.1';
```

It will work.

Alternativly you can also do this:

```
$commsDisplay = file_get_contents("http://www.dangergaming.com/comms/{$commsIP[0]}");
```

When you do that it will get the first result out of the `$commsIP` array.